Unicode scribbled character identification app for Android
I was thinking, and listening to some audio, when my mind depicted the following software character:

I did not take a picture of it. It just came to mind.
I would like to have a Unicode scribble recognizer app for Android where I could just draw what character came to mind, and, the app, would tell me what character it was, in the Unicode standard (if there was more then one it would show all of them, if there was none it would just show close matches).
Where can I find such an app?
Thank you for your cooperation.
Thank you for your development.
Thank you for your support.
Thank you for your contribution.
